# Jquery - accessing an element is giving null

Tags: jquery

I have page a where product and its image are loaded in a table.The image is initially hidden,and onmouseover I want to display the image.The image is inside a div tag,and productname is shown as a link.In the onready function,I attach event handler to the link,

```
$('a').each(function()
    {
        if( $(this).attr('id').match(/prod/)) 
        {
            $(this).mouseover(display());
        }
    });
```

and in the eventhandler(a function called display) I am calling

```
function display()
{
    $('div').each(function()
    {
        if( $(this).attr('id').match(/sx/)) 
        {
            alert("hi")
        }
    });
}
```

But, I am getting an error $("div") is null

HTML is:

```
 <table>
 <tr><td><a href="link">product name</a></td>
   <td><div class='.hidden'><table><tr><td><img   src=""></img></td></tr></table></div></td></table>
```

Comment: Updated my post a little further

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
$(this).mouseover(display());
```

with

```
$(this).mouseover(display);
```

Your code is executing the function `display()` and passes in it's return value to `mouseover`. But you need to pass a function reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make the display function anonymous, much like you hve done in the rest of yoru code:

```
$('a').each(function()
    {
        if( $(this).attr('id').match(/prod/)) 
        {
            $(this).mouseover(function() {
                $('div').each(function()
                {
                    if( $(this).attr('id').match(/sx/)) 
                    {
                        alert("hi")
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

With regard to `$("div")` is null can you clarify further. Can you tell me something on the following:

```
var obj = $("div");      //is obj null?
alert($("div").length);  //do you get a number? If so, what is it?
```